# How to get the same object properties from different items in Graphql

Tags: graphql, dry, contentful

I'm using Contentful and it's Graphql. I have a collection, that has reference to different content types, like: page, landing, format, static page etc. The content types are different, but has some overlap. I want to get name and slug from each entry, but I want to know if I can do this without

```
...on Page {
  name
  slug
}
...on Landing {
  name
  slug
}
...on Static_Contante {
  name
  slug
}
etc.
```

is there something like:

```
...on GenericCommonFields {
  name
  slug
}
```

I read about fragments, but I don't see if and how I should use them here. Should I just repeat the code, or is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with [fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments). First is to create fragment with all common item's parts like that:

```
fragment commonCollectionItems on SectionBlocksItem {
 ...on Page {
   name
   slug
 }
 ...on Landing {
   name
   slug
 }
 ...on Static_Contante {
   name
   slug
 }
}
```

And use it in your collection like:

```
someCollection {
 items {
  ...commonCollectionItems
  ... on Page { #example
   seoUrl 
   seoTitle 
  }
 }
}
```